# Android Retrofit2 RxJava, how solve error with Google authentication token?

Tags: android, token, rx-java, observable, retrofit2

Please, help me guys! I have a list files in app, these files can be marked as read and unread. When this action is executed, a request is made to the server to store this state. But I ran into an error:

```
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: <-- 400 BAD REQUEST https://api.me/api/v1/2/setDocumentAttribute?token=q4B97JQBCKcZYCjVVw6v-cFMC4I2JoMd-MmCir7VvuLZl15J_Ztqm2JpbKwraRDmqWEyZOxJWzoy_eOKv0U2XX2a-9GL_7cXkOMyT20BLaqHb3nJSGoJnPU2cCFigEtC4TLhSIh_brpF_KNNeZ8_MqzEaomiTSYVtkx6RnL7ohPLPh8ZjMK2ow%3D%3D&documentID=33fe7dcb697f613c56f449754e923c53&path=Personal&attrName=isNew (99ms)
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 03:30:00 GMT
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 97
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: {"message": "Input payload validation failed", "errors": {"token": "Security token"}}
```

Api server have such parameters:

```
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Pagination token",
            "name": "pageToken"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "(True, False) Returns hierachy only, including empty folders",
            "name": "hierarchyOnly"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Parent folder ID",
            "name": "parent"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Valid security token",
            "name": "token"
          },
          {
            "description": "An optional fields mask",
            "format": "mask",
            "type": "string",
            "name": "X-Fields",
            "in": "header"
          }
        ]
```

In Android I have rest method in ApiServiceInterface:

```
@POST("setDocumentAttribute")
    Observable<String> setDocumentAttribute(
            @Query(TOKEN) String token,
            @Query(DOCUMENT_ID) String documentId,
            @Query("path") String path,
            @Query("attrName") String attrName);
```

And here I wrote down a consistent chain of methods calls, when I made debug. I really hope that it will be clear.

```
DocCompanyPresenter
    public void onClickThumbnailToggle(DocItem docItem) {
            Log.d(TAG, "***onClickThumbnailToggle");
            if (getView() != null) {
                String docId = docItem.getDocLink();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(docId)) {
                    boolean toggle = docItem.getNewDocs()>0;
                    if (toggle) {
                        docItem.setNewDocs(0); // make star (read)
                        Log.d(TAG, "***done read");
                    } else {
                        docItem.setNewDocs(1); // make isNew (unread)
                        Log.d(TAG, "***done unread");
                    }

                    getView().updateListDocs(getDocPos(docItem.getDocLink()));
                    getView().toggleDocument(leftPanelDocIdMark,!toggle);       ->

                    docId = docId.substring(0,docId.indexOf("."));

                    toggleDocument.toggleDocument(docId,docItem.getPath(),!toggle)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe();
                }
            }
        }

        FolderCompanyFragment
         @Override
            public void toggleDocument(String folderId, boolean toggle) {
                toggleDocument.actionToggleDocument(folderId,toggle);       ->
            }

        ->

        MainActivity
        @Override
            public void actionToggleDocument(String folderId, boolean toggle) {
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FolderListFragment.TAG);
                if (fragment instanceof ActionToggleDocument) {
                    ((ActionToggleDocument) fragment).actionToggleDocument(folderId,toggle);        ->
                }
            }

        ->

        FolderListFragment
         @Override
            public void actionToggleDocument(String folderId, boolean toggle) {
                getPresenter().onFolderToggleDocument(folderId,toggle);
            }

        ->onClickThumbnailToggle -> toggleDocument.toggleDocument(docId,docItem.getPath(),!toggle)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(); <-

        RestFolderRepository
        @Override
            public Observable<String> toggleDocument(String documnetId, String path, boolean toggle) {

                return apiService.setDocumentAttribute(preferencesRepository.getToken(),documnetId,path,toggle?"isNew":"star")
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        })
                        .map(aVoid -> "OK");
            }

        FolderCompanyFragment
        @Override
            public void onClickThumbnailToggle(DocItem docItem) {
                getPresenter().onClickThumbnailToggle(docItem);
            }
```

All methods for queries to the server are similar. I suspect that something is wrong with the lifetime of the token, but how to resolve this problem. I hope someone will help me with advice. If something isn't clear, please ask me.

Comment: Please, I need some idea, some adviсe, some help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got error 400, because in my case I have to remake rest method and add one parametr like this:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("setDocumentAttribute")
    Observable<String> setDocumentAttribute(
            @Field(TOKEN) String dokkaToken,
            @Field(DOCUMENT_ID) String documentId,
            @Field("path") String path,
            @Field("attrName") String attrName,
            @Field("attrData") int attrData);
```

Then I still got error 402, this is due to the fact that I was sending incorrect parameters and I minor fix my method onClickThumbnailToggle:

```
public void onClickThumbnailToggle(DocItem docItem) {
        Log.d(TAG, "***onClickThumbnailToggle");
        if (getView() != null) {
            String docId = docItem.getDocLink();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(docId)) {
                boolean toggle = docItem.getNewDocs()>0;
                if (toggle) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "***done read");
                    docItem.setNewDocs(0); // make star (read)
                    attrData = 0;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "***done unread");
                    docItem.setNewDocs(1); // make isNew (unread)
                    attrData = 1;
                }
                getView().updateListDocs(getDocPos(docItem.getDocLink()));
                getView().toggleDocument(leftPanelDocIdMark,!toggle);
                toggleDocument.toggleDocument(docId,docItem.getPath(),ATTR_NAME, attrData)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe();
            }
    }
}
```

Also change parametr in toggleDocument in class RestFolderRepository.